# How to configure Hibernate to do not insert data into database during test phase

Tags: hibernate, persistence

Is there any way to configure Hibernate to do not insert data into database during test phase?

Answer (score 2):

The easies way to achieve this is to run whole test in one transaction and use transaction rollback at the end of the test. If you use spring framework take a look at the [TransactionConfiguration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/transaction/TransactionConfiguration.html) anotation.

Comment: In fact, I also want to test using persist, but I dont want Hibernate commit the data to DB. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is. You can use save, saveOrUpdate or whatever operation you need. Queries go to the database but everything is rolled back after the test. Here is one link i have googled for you, it is about testing hibernate daos. I am not sure it is up to date but the basic idea is there http://peterbacklund.blogspot.com/2006/11/testing-hibernate-daos-with-spring.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the flush mode to `FlushMode.NEVER`, therefore the container will not apply the changes to the database implicitly.

Also can try making the connection as read only : `session.connection().setReadOnly(true)`.